навигационные кнопки swiper-slider
Как для собственных кнопок навигации Swiper Slider задать класс, который будет применяться к ним в тот момент, когда слайды закончатся и они будут неактивными?

Без кода не понятно, у Вас дополнительные свои кнопки и оба варианта кнопок нужны, либо Вы просто хотите стилизовать кнопки слайдера?  Для того что написано, нормального решения скорее всего нет так как вероятно это происходит бессобытийно.
